# Add Exception to firewall on Mac either during installation of application or when application is launched

Tags: c++, macos, qt, installation

I have a client - server application, where I want to add a exception to firewall so that my applications can communicate properly.
I want to add add an exception to the firewall (without changing the setup for the other firewalls options).

I am using Carbon, Qt, C++. However, I feel this has more to do with some install time settings.

Comment: Consider posting also in superuser.com. I won't request closing the question as 'belongs on superuser.com' but you have better chances of getting installation time settings there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure this is would be good practice without notifying the user or asking the user for permission. Since osx has a built in system for creating application signing and the user must explicitly enable this level of security.

That being said, you should have a look at

```
/usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/socketfilterfw
```

and

```
/usr/libexec/ApplicationFirewall/com.apple.alf.plist
```

OS X also use ipfw and I'm pretty sure it supersedes any rules set by the application filter. So you could make an ipfw rule as well.

Answer (score 0):

in my opinion, if you`re opening a socket, your Mac-firewall will automatic give you the chance to allow or deny the connection.... did you try it?

Comment: Sorry, I think missed a detail there, that it should not be user interactive. This all should happen in background.

Comment: I tried what you suggested. I want set firewall to always allow incoming connections

Comment: Why shouldn't it be user interactive? You are trying to change the security of the system. If your application isn't malicious then why is there a problem with using the system behaviour?

Comment: Yes, usually the user is asked when the connection attempt is being made, and then the user can allow it once, allow always, or deny it.