# Is there a way to request for a firewall exception in .NET 6? (not only on Windows)

Tags: c#, .net, firewall, httplistener

(I don't know much about macOS)

On Windows, when an application is going to listen to a port, it will add a firewall rule for itself, and a Windows Firewall permission dialog will be shown.
Is there a way to perform this via .NET API?
My application is not for Windows only, so it is better not to use COM or other Windows-only workarounds

Comment: This sounds rather like a security risk. Why would you want to do that?

Comment: I don't think this causes security risk. The application must listen to a port that is connected to the Internet so that it can be communicated with targets. What I want is not to add a firewall rule silently, but to raise a firewall dialog for user to choose to permit, so that users do not need to manually add the rule themselves, whether via cmd or powershell or firewall gui

Comment: This greatly depends on the firewall the user is running. Even on Windows, your observed behavior isn't guaranteed since not everyone uses the Windows Firewall. There isn't a .NET system call that will tell the system to prompt the user to add the firewall rule. You would have to implement this your self and it will be OS specific as well.

Comment: _Very_ unlikely, since there could be different firewalls installed on the machine and there is no unified API to communicate with them, even less so if you need the call to be cross-platform. You can change the settings for the _default_ MacOS firewall like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2005075/add-exception-to-firewall-on-mac-either-during-installation-of-application-or-wh